# Machine Learning algorithm to get X and Y points ranges values

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
0.8496732   0.035353534 0.875817    0.035353534 0.875817    0.04419192  0.8496732   0.04419192  DATE
0.88071895  0.035353534 0.88235295  0.035353534 0.88235295  0.04419192  0.88071895  0.04419192  (
0.88235295  0.035353534 0.89542484  0.035353534 0.89542484  0.04419192  0.88235295  0.04419192  MM
0.8986928   0.035353534 0.9019608   0.035353534 0.9019608   0.04419192  0.8986928   0.04419192  /
0.9019608   0.035353534 0.9133987   0.035353534 0.9133987   0.04419192  0.9019608   0.04419192  DD
0.9150327   0.035353534 0.9183006   0.035353534 0.9183006   0.04419192  0.9150327   0.04419192  /
0.91993463  0.035353534 0.9428105   0.035353534 0.9428105   0.04419192  0.91993463  0.04419192  YYYY
0.9444444   0.035353534 0.9460784   0.035353534 0.9460784   0.04419192  0.9444444   0.04419192  )
0.85457516  0.045454547 0.86764705  0.045454547 0.86764705  0.055555556 0.85457516  0.055555556 10
0.874183    0.045454547 0.877451    0.045454547 0.877451    0.055555556 0.874183    0.055555556 /
0.88071895  0.045454547 0.8986928   0.045454547 0.8986928   0.055555556 0.88071895  0.055555556 13
0.9019608   0.045454547 0.90522873  0.045454547 0.90522873  0.055555556 0.9019608   0.055555556 /
```

Each group of these points corresponds to a certain word within a character(s).

What I want to be able to do make these points as inputs so that  I would be able to get `10/13/` is there a way to do that for all documents with the same as this one?